# How do I handle res.status(<code>).send() in async functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I've seen many different ways of handling `res.status(<code>).send(<whatever>)` especially when it comes to async functions, and I'm not sure which one is right. Can someone provide an explanation for the appropriate way to do it?

```
export const randomFunction = functions.runWith(functionDefault).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    functionSecurity.setHttpSecurityHeaders(res);

    if (req.body.automaticFail) {
        res.status(500).send(`This function automatically bombed out`);
        return Promise.reject();
    }
    
    res.status(200).send(`This function automatically succeeded`);
    return Promise.resolve(200);
}

export const randomFunction2 = functions.runWith(functionDefault).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    functionSecurity.setHttpSecurityHeaders(res);

    if (req.body.automaticFail) {
        return res.status(500).send(`This function automatically bombed out`);
    }
    
    return res.status(200).send(`This function automatically succeeded`);
}

export const randomFunction3 = functions.runWith(functionDefault).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    functionSecurity.setHttpSecurityHeaders(res);

    if (req.body.automaticFail) {
        res.status(500).send(`This function automatically bombed out`);
    }
    
    res.status(200).send(`This function automatically succeeded`);
}
```

Perhaps even none of these are correct? I'm just confused onw how asyncronous operations are supposed to work.

Comment: Use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) for error handling in `async` function.

Answer (score 0):

`randomFunction2` will work perfectly, the reason is that Node.js will end the request-response cycle after calling the `send()` function so you don't have to worry whether it is async or not.